# Data collection from multiple api services

Tags: api, web-services, data

I'm looking for an application package or library that can connect to various API web services (Google Analytics, Twitter, Facebook, YouTube, LinkedIn, MailChimp, Google+) and download selected data sets from each one for further processing.

Is similar to what dashboard services like geckoboard or dashthis are doing without the charting user interface just the backend to collect and save the data.

In case of a library, ASP.NET is preferred